replace-regexp-in-string inserting rather than replacing at some matches
This is my first question. My searches through answers to (some of the) similar questions hints that I likely have to educate myself on Match Data, but I'm asking here now anyway.
Anyway, I have a function now that seems to work well on the limited tests I have given it:
(defun debrace (in-str)
  "strip out surrounding space and braces (if present) from given string"
  (let ( (reg-ex "\\(\\}?\\s-*\\'\\)\\|\\(\\`\\s-*{?\\)") )
    (replace-regexp-in-string reg-ex "Q" in-str) ) )

I have the replacement text a "Q" for debugging purposes, but it will become an empty string.
My question is regarding why I do not get the desired results with the regexp groups the other way around, i,e. begin-stuff OR end-stuff. If I instead bind my reg-ex as
(reg-ex "\\(\\`\\s-*{?\\)\\|\\(\\}?\\s-*\\'\\)")

the match at the beginning gets replaced as desired, but the "Q" gets inserted before the end match, which doesn't get removed.
So my question is: why does this happen?
Of course I have no shortage of related questions, so any pointers to where I should start educating myself would be appreciated. It would be natural for me to just avoid that \\| and first remove the beginning part, and then the end part. But then I'd need a string variable on which to operate, but I don't know how to bind it to new values without having nested let, which seems silly, or using setq, which then seems to make the variable's scope extend beyond the let block. (The target text for my project is LaTeX documents.)
UPDATE: examples.
Using the regexp that gives me problems, those problems are apparent only when the closing brace is present. To generate these examples I am using this:
(defun tst-fct ()
  "interactive testing function for functions that take a string"
  (interactive)
  (let ((the-str
     (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert (format "input string is : |%s|\noutput string is: |%s|\n"
              the-str (manip-str the-str))))))

so the input and output are enclosed in vertical bars that are not part of those strings. (The manip-str function is just the debrace function mentioned at the top of the post, but using the different regexp.) I get:
input string is : |no space no brace|
output string is: |Qno space no braceQ|
;desired output string is the same
input string is : |   spaces no braces   |
output string is: |Qspaces no bracesQ|
;desired output string is the same
input string is : |{braces no external spaces}|
output string is: |Qbraces no external spacesQ}|
;desired output string is: |Qbraces no external spacesQ|
input string is : |   {  braces and spaces  }   |
output string is: |Q  braces and spaces  Q}   |
;desired output string is: |Q  braces and spaces  Q|

So my problem is that I don't want that closing brace, or any of the spaces subsequent to it to appear, as they do in those last two examples.
The problem is apparent even when that ending brace is the only thing that matches:
input string is : |just right brace}|
output string is: |Qjust right braceQ}|
;desired output string is: |Qjust right braceQ|

But the brace character doesn't seem to be the problem. Here I'm using
(reg-ex "\\(\\`\\s-*B?\\)\\|\\(E?\\s-*\\'\\)")

and find the same problem:
input string is : |   B external spaces diff delimsE  |
output string is: |Q external spaces diff delimsQE  |
;desired output string is: |Q external spaces diff delimsQ|
input string is : |only final delimE|
output string is: |Qonly final delimQE|
;desired output string is: |Qonly final delimQ|

But if I swap the order of those groups in the regular expression,
(reg-ex "\\(E?\\s-*\\'\\)\\|\\(\\`\\s-*B?\\)")

everything seems to work fine:
input string is : |   B external spaces diff delimsE  |
output string is: |Q external spaces diff delimsQ|
input string is : |only final delimE|
output string is: |Qonly final delimQ|


I don't understand your specification: can you give an example of an input string, the desired output string and the actual output with each regexp (with the debugging Q included)?

Thanks @NickD, I have added examples that hopefully clarify the problem I'm describing. Generating those made me think the problem might be related to the quoted closing brace character, but apparently that isn't what is causing this behaviour.

I took the liberty of adding desired output strings in almost all cases (except the last block). Please check them carefully and fix them if I have misunderstood your intent.

I don't have time to go through that at present, but: M-x re-builder will highlight the matched groups.  Use that to check that you're matching what you think you're matching?

Thanks again @NickD, yes every one of your added comments corresponds to the desired output string I have in mind.
